# "Seek the truth in X" vs. "seek the truth with X"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, prepositions, collocation

Ran into the phrase

> to seek the truth in love

meaning "seek truth without hurting others in the process". I feel it should be "with" rather than "in." No rule in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting "without hurting others".

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it,

You *seek the truth **in** love* when you mean seeking the truth **within** the love. The truth will be found inside the love, within it. The word **in** describes the "location" of that love.

You *seek the truth **with** love* when you mean seeking the truth with the love you have, **you use it** (the love) to find the truth. The truth is somewhere out there, not inside the love. For example, you seek the truth in friendship, with the use of love. The word **with** describes the means/way (which in this case is *love* itself) to find the truth.

Comment: Thanks, that's how it sounds to me, too:  does this love have any truth in it.  I believe it should be "with" rather than "in" if the intent is to seek truth in a loving way, but I'm running into arguments.

Comment: Yup. That's correct, from what I could comprehend it. *Seek the truth with love* is definitely a wiser thing to choose, don't you think?'

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the possible interpretation of *in* which gives a different meaning (*look for where within love truth is to be found*), I find them to view *love* in two different ways:

> Seek the truth with love

views *love* as a quality with which you might act

> Seek the truth in love

views *love* as a state which you may be in.

I find the latter more encompassing and suggestive; but functionally they are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine with some subtle difference in meaning. I think what you are trying to say is *through love*.